# Regarding union of intersection and intersection of union for arbitrary events

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was working through Probability and Measure by Patrick Billingsley and I came across the following question.

Let $A_{1},A_{2},....A_{n}$ be arbitrary events, and put $U_{k} = \cup(A_{i_{1}}\cap...\cap A_{i_{k}})$ and $I_{k} = \cap(A_{i_{1}}\cup...\cup A_{i_{k}})$ where the union and intersection extend over all the k-tuples satisfying $1\leq i_{1} < i_{2}....<i_{k}\leq n$. Show that $U_{k} = I_{n-k+1}$.

I can easily see $U_{k} \subseteq I_{n-k+1}$ but I am not able to obtain the result other way around. Any hints for proving $I_{n-k+1} \subseteq U_{k}$?. Your help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have arrived at a solution.

Suppose $\omega \in I_{n-k+1}$ implies $\omega$ belongs to atleast k-events. If $\omega$ belongs to k-1 events only , then there exists an arbitrary n-k+1 events such that $\omega$ does not belong to anyone of them. This implies $\omega \notin I_{n-k+1}$

Since $\omega \in I_{n-k+1}$ implies $\omega$ belongs to atleast k-events then by definition of $U_{k}$, $\omega \in U_{k}$ which proves $ I_{n-k+1} \subseteq U_{k}$